# SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure already activated but it's saying it is not

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

we have a top level intranet site under /.  We recently purchased a 3rd party helpdesk system that I've been told to rebrand to make look like the top level intranet site.  We installed that under the /sites path, so /sites/helpdesk.  I tried activating the publishing feature at the site level and got the message:

> Site  The feature being activated is a Site scoped feature which has a
>   dependency on a Site Collection scoped feature which has not been
>   activated. Please activate the following feature before trying again:
>   SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure
>   f6924d36-2fa8-4f0b-b16d-06b7250180fa
>
> Web  The Site scoped feature being activated has a dependency on
>   hidden Site scoped feature
>   'FeatureDefinition/22a9ef51-737b-4ff2-9346-694633fe4416' (ID:
>   '22a9ef51-737b-4ff2-9346-694633fe4416'). Hidden features cannot be
>   auto-activated across scopes. There may be one or more visible Site
>   scoped features that auto-activate the dependent hidden feature.

So, I have actually googled this and read many posts about it but I have not seen anyone who ran into a situation where the dependency feature was already activated.  When I went to the top level site "/" collection and discovered that the SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure is already activated.  So I guess I am wondering why it's not picking that up and if it's OK to deactivate it and reactivate it and whether that should fix the issue ...

Comment: Thanks - you know I checked there first and didn't see any site collection admin options so I assumed it had to be done at the root level.  I checked and I was not a site collection admin for the helpdesk site - added myself and voila, the options appeared and I was able to add the features.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are settings specific to each site collection. You say that it is enabled at the root site, but you installed it under /sites/helpdesk. You need to turn on the publishing infrastructure at the /sites/helpdesk level as this is a different site collection that the root site collection.

Comment: Came here to say the same thing but you beat me to it. +1 to you.